# schema validation for soap service in camel

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, cxf

Have hosted soap service using camel-cxf component with default POJO data format. Want to do schema validation and instead fault need to return custom soap message.

Answer (score 0):

There are many places and many techniques to do that. It depends on your requirements and design solution.

You can do it by custom code in one of inbound CXF interceptors before request reaches first processor after Camel `from` endpoint.

You can do it by using Camel Validate component (maybe start looking from here: [Apache Camel: Validation Component](http://camel.apache.org/validation.html)

Some time ago, after playing with different approaches I ended up with custom Processor to do validation (due to my requirements - must be inside Route, must provide all errors/warnings at once(not first only), must create custom error response with details about all errors, get better as possible performance and so on...
I used standard `javax.xml.validation` package.

That option is not too hard, but more coding required.

Code must create instance of `javax.xml.validation.Schema` out of XSD file.
It is thread safe and it can be cached.

Then out of it `javax.xml.validation.Validator` can be created and used.
It is not thread safe, so new one must be created every time. (It is not costly operation anyway).

Then to collect all errors and warnings at once instead of getting validation exception from first error/warrning custom Error Handler implementing `org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler` interface need to be provided to validator in that case. There you can collect all exception and warnings from validation and deal with them after full validation completed.

With CXF POJO format - body in Camel Message actually is not a SOAP Message body, but it
is `org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList;` where SOAP Message body POJO is element 0, and if message has more parts they are there too.

To use `javax.xml.validation.Validator` Body POJO must be marshalled to `javax.xml.transform.Source`

```
MyPojoClass bodyObject = ((MessageContentsList) exchange.getIn().getBody()).get(0);
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
                .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

Schema requestedSchema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaUrl);

Validator validator = requestedSchema.newValidator();
// custom handler to collect all errors and warnings
SchemaValidationErrorHandler errHandler = new SchemaValidationErrorHandler();
        validator.setErrorHandler(errHandler);

//Custom method convertPojo - uses JAXB Marshaller in standard way
Source xmlSource = convertPojo(bodyObject);

validator.validate(xmlSource);
```

After all if Error Handler collects warnings and errors and does not throw Exception right away, all errors/warnings will be in it and can be handled as needed.

P.S. Performance is better when Schema object created ones and cached somewhere. Schema object creation is costly operation.